# Enabling Scrollbar in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm having a problem right now where my WPF application hides anything below the fold when the window is too small vertically.  How can I use XAML to get a vertical scrollbar to appear for the entire app so the user can scroll to see the rest of the content?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Put a ScrollViewer inside your Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

    <ScrollViewer >
        <!-- Window content here -->
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

Comment: When I'm putting `ScrollViewer` the scrollbar appears, in my case, a vertical one, because I'm using animation to move the item down, and when it reaches the bottom of the window scrollbar shows, but I'm not able to see the scrollbar cursor or do scrolling via mouse.