# WPF margins don't add up

Tags: wpf, grid

I just started working with WPF and I am trying to set up a grid with four rows that have a height of 150. That would take up 600 of my 800 pixels that I set for the height. I then set my top margin to 30 and my bottom margin to 170  to give myself some room for controls at the bottom.

Everything looks great in design view but when I run my applications the bottom row has some area cut off.

Design View
[image]

Running View
[image]

I don't understand what is causing this discrepancy between these views.

```
 <Page x:Class="EzTargetProject.HomePage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1280"
Title="HomePage">

<Grid  Margin="20,30,20, 170" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4" Background="Gray" ShowGridLines="True">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Name -->
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: I may have noticed what the issue is but I would like a confirmation if anyone can give me one. Is the navigation bar for a page taken into account for margins meaning my margins are off by however many pixels the navigation bar is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the bottom margin if you want to set the height of your grid.

If you always want to have a 600px height grid, just set it.

I'd use a ScrollViewer as a parent to let the user see the controls you are going to set under the grid (if the user wants to have a little window forexample):
[Enabling Scrollbar in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736153/enabling-scrollbar-in-wpf)

Comment: That worked perfectly and made my design a lot more flexible for other screens. I will give you the answer in 5 minutes when it lets me. Thank you.

Comment: Btw was the way above not working because of the navigation bar?

Comment: I suppose it was because it always try to let that margin... and there weren't 170px under the grid. I don't know if the window was more little than the design one or if the bottom of the window was allocated for another element 8-)