# Insert a vertical scrollbar to see the content of tab items

Tags: c#, wpf

I was working with WinForms and I am kind of new in WPF, I want to insert a vertical scrollbar to see all the elements content in my TabItems, this is my [previous WinForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nhqdj.png) and this is my [new WPF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/479kQ.png): I have implemented the following xaml-code:

```
   <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,199.2">
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl">
            <TabItem Header="1" Background="#008000"/>
            <TabItem Header="2" Background="#1e90ff"/>
            <TabItem Header="3" Background="#bd3f02"/>
            <ScrollBar></ScrollBar>
        </TabControl>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: try scroll viewer = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736153/enabling-scrollbar-in-wpf

Comment: The usual way to approach what your requirement looks like is to have a listbox with a wrappanel as it's itemspanel. Then template out data into the various graphs. There's a fair bit to explain if you're totally new to wpf though. Are the graphs the same just showing different data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to display inside of your tabs, your issue might be solved by using a suitable items control which comes with a `ScrollViewer` out-of-the-box. Since I do not know your exact use case, I present you a general solution. From the images that you provided you want your tab content to be scrollable. To achieve this, remove the `ScrollBar` and place a `ScrollViewer` into each of the tabs that you want to scroll.

```xaml
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,199.2">
   <TabControl x:Name="tabControl">
      <TabItem Header="1" Background="#008000">
         <ScrollViewer>
            <!-- Your tab content here -->
         </ScrollViewer>
      </TabItem>
      <TabItem Header="2" Background="#1e90ff"/>
      <TabItem Header="3" Background="#bd3f02"/>
   </TabControl>
</StackPanel>
```

The vertical scrollbar will be shown if the content exceed its container by default. If you want to display it always, set the `VerticalScrollBarVisibility` property to `Visible`.

```xaml
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
```

Comment: thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

What you might want to try is encapsulating the content in a ScrollViewer like so :

```
<StackPanel>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <Grid>
            <!-- YOUR CONTENT HERE -->
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I just tried that way, but it is not working as the result I was expecting

Comment: You might want to add a fixed height for your content for it to work. You can also force the display of the horizontal and vertical scriollbar